# Treat generic types as one

Tags: c#, generics

I have a question regarding generics in C#. I would like to treat a generic class/interface as one type in any collection and be able to execute the method in `foreach` loop.

```
public interface IRunner<T> where T : struct
{
    void Run(T data);
}

public class FooRunner : IRunner<int>
{
    public void Run(int data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class BarRunner : IRunner<float>
{
    public void Run(float data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Having above structure I cannot assign instances of IRunner into one collection because I would need to provide type

```
var runners = new List<IRunner<?>>();
```

What I can do it to create non-generic IRunner interface then I would be able to assign them into collection

```
public interface IRunner { }

public interface IRunner<T> : IRunner where T : struct
{
    void Run(T data);
}
```

Above construct allows me to gather the runners:

```
var runners = new List<IRunner> { new BarRunner(), new FooRunner() };
```

Since IRunner does not contain any method I am not able to execte Run() for any memebers which I would like to.

I know that this might be achived using reflections but I see it as a error-prone and dirty solution.

Is there anyway to achive solution like below:

```
var runners = new List<IRunner<?>> { new BarRunner(), new FooRunner() };

foreach (var runner in runners)
{
    T data = GetData(); // get some data
    runner.Run(data);
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what's wrong with `List<IRunner>`... Since to call the method you need to provide type you can simply cast it  `((IRunner<T>)runner).Run(data)`... Basically as soon as you figure out how you want  to call it you should be able to cast... (Note: I'd just give up and use reflection via `dynamic`)

Comment: If you want a specific behavior, you limit the generic parameter to something that has that behavior. By default you only have access to the "smalest common denominator" of functions between all *possible* types. But as you limit it down, more functions will become avalible. Limiting it down to require a specific Interface is a time honodred tradition

Comment: Are you certain taht generics are you goal and not just plain old Polymorphy? Lately a lot of questions appeared where people went for Generics, but actually needed basic Polymorphy.

Comment: How about give up on generics and have `IRunner { void Run(object); }`?

Comment: @Dialecticus boxing. OP has structs as generic constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to `Run` with dynamic types, you may refactor as below. However there is no type checking during compile time, and the app may crash during runtime if inappropriate argument type is passed during method invocation.

```
    public interface IRunner
    {
        void Run(object value);
    }

    public interface IRunner<T>:IRunner
    {
        void Run<T>(T value);
    }

    public abstract class BaseRunner<T>:IRunner<T>
    {
        public void Run(object value)
        {
           if(!(value is T arg)) 
              throw new ArugmentException($"{nameof(value)} must be of type {typeof(T)});
           Run(arg);
        }
        public abstract void Run(T value);
    }

public class FooRunner:BaseRunner<int>
{
    public override void Run(int value)
    {
       // your implementation
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var runners = new List<IRunner>{new FooRunner(),new BarRunner()};
foreach(var runner in runners) runner.Run(arg);
```

Comment: You will lose type safety and introduce boxing.

Comment: @GuruStron yes indeed, but it is a lot cleaner and performant than using Reflection

Answer (score 0):

Best option(at least in terms of readability) I can suggest in this particular case is to use [`Enumerable.OfType<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1) method for type check in pair with non-generic `IRunner` interface:

```
int i = 1;

foreach (var runner in runners.OfType<IRunner<int>>())
{
    runner.Run(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way of achieving that without doing some boxing or reflection or even loosing type-safety (as highlighted on previous answers), but **if** your use case allows it, you can instead of having a generic interface IRunner you could have a generic Run method with the struct generic constraint. This will allow you to have a generic store and worry about the value type only when calling the Run method.

```
public interface IRunner
{
    void Run<T>(T data) where T: struct;
}
```